# How to make a sum which involves a count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query where I make a COUNT:

```
SELECT FECHAGENERACION, IDAPLICACION, COUNT(*) as NRO_REGISTROS
FROM  ADMBLOQMON.BOC_MAEBLOQAUX_BLOQ_MONO  WHERE fechageneracion between '01/12/20' AND '02/12/20' AND IDAPLICACION = 01
GROUP BY FECHAGENERACION, IDAPLICACION
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Which gives me the following results:

```
01/12/20    01    62172
02/12/20    01    61812
```

How can I make this query also give me that sum of the counts 62172 and 61812? I am struggling so hard please help

Comment: PL/SQL is the *scripting* language for Oracle.  I added the Oracle tag, because that would be the database you are using.

Comment: *Programming* language, surely? You would *script* in SQL\*Plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use `GROUPING SETS`:

```
SELECT FECHAGENERACION, IDAPLICACION, COUNT(*) as NRO_REGISTROS
FROM ADMBLOQMON.BOC_MAEBLOQAUX_BLOQ_MONO 
WHERE fechageneracion between DATE '2020-01-12' AND DATE '2020-02-12' AND
      IDAPLICACION = 01
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (FECHAGENERACION, IDAPLICACION), () )
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Note that I fixed the date constants using standard YYYY-MM-DD format (I had to guess what the dates mean so that might be wrong).  I strongly recommend using standard formats for dates so local settings do not change the meaning of your code (and the code is more readable).

Comment: This works for the solution, thank you very much mr Gordon, why is it important to declare DATE in the constants tho? Optimization?

Comment: Hey, if I wanted to get the average also I would need to use avg function or is there something similar to grouping sets function? thank you

Comment: @BugsOverflow . . . The average is trickier.  You might want to ask a new question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hello Gordon, yes sir I will in 50 mins, gotta wait for new question, I will provide desired result and example, also what I have tried